# How can I run code formatter in a standalone fashion (without executing IDE)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use "code formatter" in VSCode, without executing the VSCode IDE.
For example, IntelliJ IDEA has its own standalone formatted binary `bin/format.sh`.
Is there any way to run "code formatter" in a standalone fashion? Like, `bin/code --formatter ...` or something?
Please help me out!